# AG grid hide empty columns

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to implement an AG-grid with simple row grouping and trying to hide the columns that are empty. Is there any way to achieve that?
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can hide a column by setting `hide=true` on the Column Definition for that column.

If you want to achieve this dynamically, then you can leverage `columnApi.applyColumnState()`:

```
  hideGold() {
    this.gridColumnApi.applyColumnState({
      state: [{ colId: 'gold', hide: true }],
    });
  }
```

See this implemented in the [following sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/YrckGvuS93gFUNqF?preview).

Documentation on [Column State](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/column-state/).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was looking for something different, I wanted to check the column values and if it is empty only then hide it.

Comment: You can iterate over all the row data using `api.ForEachNode` and check if `node.data` or `node.aggData` is empty, for all nodes. Based on that you can hide the column as shown above.

Comment: A column can have a valueGetter, and having data without the valueGetter does not allow to make a reliable solution.

Answer (score 1):

This could help i write two function in a tool.ts
the first one returns the value of each column
and the second check if column is empty then hide it

```
    /**
   *
   * @param o // node data
   * @param propertyName  // columns name = the filed of the headerName
   * @returns
   * This function infers the type of the object T
   * and casts the property name to the key type K,
   * returning the property of the object using the given key T[K]
   */
  public static getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, propertyName: K): T[K] {
    return o[propertyName];
  }
  /**
   *
   * @param gridApi
   * @param columnDefs
   * @param columnApi
   * Hide empty columns if all the column is empty
   */
  static hideEmptyColumns(
    gridApi: GridApi,
    columnDefs: any,
    columnApi: ColumnApi
  ) {
    let headers = []; // Headers array to store headersName fields
    if (gridApi) {
      columnDefs.forEach((col) => {
        col.children.forEach((child) => {
          headers.push(child.field);
        });
      });
      const columnsEmptyCheck = [];
      headers.forEach((it) => columnsEmptyCheck.push(true));
      // loop for each node
      gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
        //loop throw headers
        headers.forEach((header, idx) => {
          const value = this.getProperty(node.data, header);
          if (value?.length === 0 || value === undefined) {
            columnsEmptyCheck[idx] = false;
          }
        });
      });

      /**
       * make the empty columns that has false unvisible
       */

      columnsEmptyCheck.forEach((element, index) => {
        if (element === false) {
          columnApi.setColumnsVisible([headers[index]], false);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

AG-grid provides a `getValue` method that abstracts the value getting logic.
It also provides a `rowDataChanged` hook very handy for this use case.

You can find below a basic example to run on `rowDataChanged` that hides empty columns.

```
hideEmptyColumns(params: RowDataChangedEvent) {
  const columns = params.columnApi.getAllColumns();
  const rowsNodes = params.api.getRenderedNodes();
  columns.forEach(column => {
    const isColumnEmpty = !rowsNodes.some(rowNode => {
      const value = params.api.getValue(column, rowNode);
      return typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null;
    });
    column.setVisible(!isColumnEmpty);
  });
}
```